# Placing the modal at the bottom for all resolutions

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap4-modal

I'm using react-bootstrap modal in my project. I need to place the modal at bottom of all the resolutions. For example, I can place the modal at bottom by changing css bottom property to -74% in 1080x1920 resolutions. But for other devices it is not the same.

```
<div role="dialog" aria-modal="true" class="fade modal show" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; padding-left: 0px;">
   <div role="document" class="modal-dialog sc-modal">
      <div class="modal-content">...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>



.sc-modal{
    width:100% !important; 
    top: unset;
    bottom:0%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important;
}
```

How to place the modal at the bottom for all device resolutions ?

Comment: You have to use "position" property for this. Add "postion: fixed; bottom:0" to your css code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position` should help you fix the modal at the bottom of the window.

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
   position: fixed;       
   bottom: 0;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%);
}
```